# Convert string elements in series to floats in Red language

Tags: variables, type-conversion, rebol, red

I want to convert many decimal numbers available as strings to floats in one go. I am trying following code which combines these strings into a series and then convert them to floats. This works all right but fails if there is an error:

```
a: "1.5" 
b: ""
c: "3.7"
invars: [a b c]

print a
print type? a

set invars foreach x invars [append [] to-float reduce x]  ; code to convert string series to float series; 

print a
print type? a
```

The error is:

```
*** Script Error: cannot MAKE/TO float! from: ""
*** Where: to
*** Stack: to-float
```

For error correction, I tried following code:

```
temp: []
foreach x invars [
    y: copy ""
    either error? [set [y] to-float reduce x]
        [append temp reduce x]         ; put original value if not convertable
        [append temp reduce y]  ]
print temp 
set invars temp
print a 
print type? a
```

But this is also not working. Where is the problem and how can this be corrected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forall invars [invars/1:  load get invars/1]
>> invars
== [1.5 [] 3.7]
```

and if you want to get rid of the empty blocks

```
>> replace/all invars block! 0
== [1.5 0 3.7]
```

and if you really want to do all in (:less:) steps

```
forall invars [invars/1: either empty? invars/1: get invars/1 [0.0] [load invars/1]]
```

After you can set your variables again.

But if you want just set your variables, you have to do

```
foreach x invars [set :x load get x]
```

with to-float

```
 foreach x invars [either empty? get x [set :x 0] [set :x to-float get x]]
```

and finally an all error safe version with to-float

```
foreach x invars [attempt [set :x to-float get x]]
== 3.7
>> a
== 1.5
>> b
== ""
>> c
== 3.7
```

Comment: Where  do I put `to-float` ?

Comment: If you use a solution with **either empty?** you could replace **load** with **to-float**

Comment: Which one is not working? All versions work as described. Use a new fresh console

Comment: Ok. I was setting invars again to output of above code.

Comment: Can you point me to documentation link where use of `:x` (colon before variable) is described?

Comment: maybe  http://www.rebol.org/ml-display-message.r?m=rmlBPQQ or http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-4.html

Comment: @rnso Rebol documentation: [5.4 Getting Words](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-4.html#section-5.4)

Comment: `set :x` is repeated in your example, can write
`set x either empty? get x [0.0][to float! get x]`

Comment: There is always room for enhancements.) This way is already shown in one of the versions above.